# How to get `conda env list` to hide an environment without removing it?

Tags: python, conda

I have a virtual environment in a folder which I have not yet activated. Running `conda env list` will not list this environment.

However, after I have activated the environment with Conda for the first time, now every time I run `conda env list` this environment will be included.

Is there a way to *ignore* the environment in `conda env list`, without removing it (since this removes the whole folder)?
I want to keep the folder without removing it and without Conda listing it every time.

Comment: Not sure if I got your point, but if I did, you should just create a new env and not use the old one.

Comment: Hi @wagnifico, perhaps I can elaborate on whats not that clear?

Comment: Why do you want to hide it from conda? I dont see the point.

Comment: I created some test environments in folders - I want to keep them, but don't want to forever see them how conda lists them

Comment: Got it. Only thing I can think of is removing them but [keeping a list of the packages](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#building-identical-conda-environments) so you can reinstall them in the future if you want.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts @wagnifico, just wanted to know, if this is the only way to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no way through configuration or otherwise out-of-the-box options to designate specific environments to be ignored by the `conda env list` command. However, if we look under the hood at how Conda generates this list, we can at least implement a workaround.

### Conda User Environment Tracking

Conda tracks environments in two ways:

1. Environments located in any of the `envs_dirs` directories are automatically discovered. You can check `conda config --show envs_dirs` to see which directories that includes. Such environments will not be ignorable in `conda env list` without altering the internals of how `conda-env` works (i.e., you'd have to fork the `conda` code and add new functionality).
2. Any time a user activates an environment, it gets added to a user-specific tracking file, namely,

   ```
   ~/.conda/environments.txt
   ```

   where `~` is the user home directory. Purging this file of environments you wish to hide should remove the environment from the `conda env list` output, at least until it is activated again.

### Automated Workaround Example

If you'd like a more automated purging, you could include a line in your shell initialization file (e.g., `.bash_profile`) to remove entries from this file using something like `sed` and a regex to match the environments you wish to omit.

As a concrete example of this, I frequently encounter this problem as Snakemake user. Snakemake automatically generates Conda environments and uses them to run code in reproducible (-ish) contexts. These environments all get generated under a `.snakemake/` directory and eventually start to dominate my `conda env list` output. This is an absolute bother, since I never intend to manually activate any of these environments, plus they are all named by hashes, so it is practically impossible to recognize their contents by prefix.

To automatically purge these, I can add the following to my `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`:

```bash
sed -i '/\.snakemake/d' ~/.conda/environments.txt
```

This will still lead to transiently showing these auto-generated environments temporarily, but they'll get purged every time a new shell launches. Hopefully, such transient cases aren't a major bother, otherwise I imagine more creative solutions to this are also workable, e.g., triggering the purge operation whenever the file is altered.

Comment: This works. Too bad conda haven't implemented this themselves e.g. via a blacklist.